# Where to get realistic data for ABC-Costing in textile industry

Tags: data-request, industry

First, let me explain what I am trying to do. For my graduation work with focus on automation I would like to show the impact of "Sewbots" (SoftWear Automation) on garment manufacturing.

My teacher suggested doing so by applying activity-based costing for a production line and then, by hypothesy, on a partly automated one. (I know one system of SewBots costs approx. 50.000 - 100.000, it can replace up to 17 workersand needs 1 supervisor for up to 5 production lines.)

I found some data on ABC in garment production but none of it seems complete (ex. http://journal-archieves30.webs.com/602-625.pdf).

Can someone suggest some sources where to get complete realistic data of activities, cost drivers, rates etc. in textile industry?

Every advice is appreciated.